# string.find выдает неправильное значение

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

```lua
local num = string.find("i want this to work --", "--")
return num
```

Вот этот код по идее должен вернуть 21, но возвращает 1

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 3):

Символ `-` является "специальным" в шаблонах Lua и является "нежадным" квантификатором, аналогичным `*?` в регулярных выражениях.

Его надо экранировать с помощью символа `%`:

```
string.find("i want this to work --", "%-%-")
```

См. [пример работы кода онлайн](https://ideone.com/QoKFD7).

Другие специальные символы в [шаблонах Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html) (на англ.):

- `(` - начало захватывающей подмаски
- `)` - конец захватывающей подмаски
- `.` - любой символ
- `%` - экранирующий символ
- `+` - жадный квантификатор, находящий модифицируемый шаблон 1 и более раз
- `-` - нежадный квантификатор, находящий модифицируемый шаблон 0 и более раз
- `*` - жадный квантификатор, находящий модифицируемый шаблон 0 и более раз
- `?` - жадный квантификатор, находящий модифицируемый шаблон 1 или 0 раз
- `[` - начало символьного класса
- `^` - начало строки
- `$` - конец строки